# get number of day in javascript date object

Tags: javascript, date, format, yahoo

```
//27 <- today day number
new Date().getDay() = new Date().getUTCDay() //<- 5 (friday)? what?
```

Do I have to parse the result with `.toString()` or use something like `YUI.Date.format()`?

Comment: ^ I just had the same thought myself; couldn't resist upvoting.

Comment: It is not clear what is expected as an answer. Question is not relevant with the answers below. It is confusing to assign UTCDay to getDay.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're looking for [`.getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate):

```
new Date().getDate();
```

`.getDay()` returns the day number 0 (Sunday) to 6 (Saturday).

Answer (score 4):

The one you are looking for is `.getDate()`, not `.getDay()`

[Date Object Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
new Date().getDate()
```

Answer (score 1):

getDay and getUTCDay returns the number of the weekday. You need getDate() and etUTCDate()